# spring, hibernate, MVC, how to detect what is wrong with mapping

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat, netbeans-8

I download solution and tray 2 tutorials using Netbeans 8.1 from  and 
P1. [Spring Hibernate Integration Example Tutorial (Spring 4 + Hibernate 3 and Hibernate 4)](http://www.journaldev.com/3524/spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial-spring-4-hibernate-3-and-hibernate-4)
P2. [Spring MVC Hibernate MySQL Integration CRUD Example Tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial)
Original projects was with eclipse. I used Netbeans.

P1 Works fine.

when I run P2 I got:

HTTP Status 404 - 
and
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI as can be seen below.

```
15-Apr-2016 14:59:46.813 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-24] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\IT\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\conf\Catalina\localhost\SpringMVCHibernate.xml
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Apr 15 14:59:57 CDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 383 ms
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Fri Apr 15 14:59:58 CDT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/persons],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.listPersons(org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/person/add],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.addPerson(com.journaldev.spring.model.Person)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/remove/{id}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.removePerson(int)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/edit/{id}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.editPerson(int,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
INFO : org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO : org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder - HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
INFO : org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
INFO : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 8082 ms
15-Apr-2016 15:00:06.429 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-24] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\IT\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\conf\Catalina\localhost\SpringMVCHibernate.xml has finished in 19,616 ms
15-Apr-2016 15:00:06.433 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-22] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SpringMVCHibernate]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHibernate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

Here is what was deployed:

```
Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is ...

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          META-INF
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          WEB-INF
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\META-INF

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2016  07:45 AM                77 context.xml
04/15/2016  07:55 AM               125 MANIFEST.MF
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          maven
04/15/2016  07:55 AM                 0 war-tracker
               3 File(s)            202 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\META-INF\maven

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          com.journaldev.spring
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\META-INF\maven\com.journaldev.spring

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          SpringMVCHibernate
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\META-INF\maven\com.journaldev.spring\SpringMVCHibernate

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2016  07:55 AM               144 pom.properties
04/15/2016  07:55 AM             6,127 pom.xml
               2 File(s)          6,271 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          classes
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          lib
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          spring
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          views
07/19/2014  08:58 PM             1,206 web.xml
               1 File(s)          1,206 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF\classes

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          com
04/15/2016  07:55 AM             1,111 log4j.xml
               1 File(s)          1,111 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF\classes\com

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          journaldev
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF\classes\com\journaldev

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          spring
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF\classes\com\journaldev\spring

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          dao
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          model
04/15/2016  07:55 AM             2,576 PersonController.class
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          service
               1 File(s)          2,576 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF\classes\com\journaldev\spring\dao

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2016  07:55 AM               428 PersonDAO.class
04/15/2016  07:55 AM             3,306 PersonDAOImpl.class
               2 File(s)          3,734 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF\classes\com\journaldev\spring\model

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2016  07:55 AM             1,534 Person.class
               1 File(s)          1,534 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF\classes\com\journaldev\spring\service

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2016  07:55 AM               440 PersonService.class
04/15/2016  07:55 AM             1,587 PersonServiceImpl.class
               2 File(s)          2,027 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF\lib

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/28/2015  04:11 PM           445,288 antlr-2.7.7.jar
03/15/2015  11:53 AM             4,467 aopalliance-1.0.jar
04/06/2016  12:33 PM           119,683 aspectjrt-1.7.4.jar
03/15/2015  11:53 AM           160,519 commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
03/15/2015  11:53 AM            96,221 commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
02/28/2015  04:11 PM           313,898 dom4j-1.6.1.jar
03/15/2015  12:10 PM            75,311 hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
03/15/2015  12:10 PM         5,230,007 hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar
04/06/2016  12:33 PM           645,914 hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar
02/28/2015  04:08 PM           113,371 hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
02/28/2015  04:11 PM            76,551 jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
02/28/2015  04:11 PM           714,194 javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
02/27/2015  11:25 AM             2,497 javax.inject-1.jar
02/28/2015  04:08 PM            57,183 jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
02/28/2015  04:08 PM            11,558 jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
02/28/2015  04:08 PM            27,717 jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
03/14/2015  08:32 AM            16,517 jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar
02/28/2015  04:11 PM           414,240 jstl-1.2.jar
03/16/2016  02:50 PM           391,834 log4j-1.2.15.jar
03/15/2015  11:53 AM           724,213 mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar
03/14/2015  08:32 AM            26,084 slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
04/06/2016  09:46 AM             8,869 slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
03/15/2015  11:53 AM           352,700 spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
03/15/2015  11:53 AM           669,978 spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
03/15/2015  11:53 AM           974,938 spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
03/15/2015  11:53 AM           973,502 spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
03/15/2015  11:53 AM           204,745 spring-expression-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
03/15/2015  11:53 AM           424,466 spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
03/15/2015  11:53 AM           366,892 spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
03/15/2015  11:53 AM           248,201 spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
04/09/2015  11:22 AM           667,960 spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
04/09/2015  11:22 AM           662,385 spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
02/28/2015  04:12 PM           109,318 xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
              33 File(s)     15,331,221 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF\spring

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          appServlet
07/19/2014  08:58 PM               380 root-context.xml
               1 File(s)            380 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF\spring\appServlet

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/19/2014  08:58 PM             3,242 servlet-context.xml
               1 File(s)          3,242 bytes

 ... apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\SpringMVCHibernate\WEB-INF\views

04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/15/2016  02:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/19/2014  08:58 PM             2,484 person.jsp
               1 File(s)          2,484 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
              49 File(s)     15,355,988 bytes
```

My question is As long as I keep the original files, how can I detect what is wrong with mapping?

Thanks for help.

M Toma

Update

personControler.java

```
package com.journaldev.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.journaldev.spring.model.Person;
import com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonService;

@Controller
public class PersonController {

    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="personService")
    public void setPersonService(PersonService ps){
        this.personService = ps;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }

    //For add and update person both
    @RequestMapping(value= "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p){

        if(p.getId() == 0){
            //new person, add it
            this.personService.addPerson(p);
        }else{
            //existing person, call update
            this.personService.updatePerson(p);
        }

        return "redirect:/persons";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id){

        this.personService.removePerson(id);
        return "redirect:/persons";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editPerson(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("person", this.personService.getPersonById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }

}
```

When I run application in netbeas, it is the one who deploy and start web on sever. I am not the one to write url address.

Netbeans let me by using right click on menu (server - tomcat - SpringMVCHibernate) to start, stop, open in browser.

I tried some others url address but no success.

All sources can be seen on the address of P2.

**Update**

I change log4j.xml level and below is what I get for open in browser:

```
TRACE: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Bound request context to thread: uri: /SpringMVCHibernate/
method: GET
QueryString: null
Parameters:
Headers:
    Name: host  Value: localhost:8080
    Name: user-agent    Value: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
    Name: accept    Value: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Name: accept-language   Value: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Name: accept-encoding   Value: gzip, deflate
    Name: dnt   Value: 1
    Name: connection    Value: keep-alive

DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing GET request for [/SpringMVCHibernate/]
TRACE: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@43edc0b9] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/]
TRACE: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@170563eb] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
TRACE: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - No handler mapping found for [/]
TRACE: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@5256ecaa] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
TRACE: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - No handler mapping found for [/]
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHibernate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
TRACE: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Cleared thread-bound request context: uri: /SpringMVCHibernate/
method: GET
QueryString: null
Parameters:
Headers:
    Name: host  Value: localhost:8080
    Name: user-agent    Value: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
    Name: accept    Value: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Name: accept-language   Value: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Name: accept-encoding   Value: gzip, deflate
    Name: dnt   Value: 1
    Name: connection    Value: keep-alive

DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
TRACE: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/SpringMVCHibernate/]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[appServlet]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[2ms]; status=[OK]
TRACE: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/SpringMVCHibernate/]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[appServlet]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[2ms]; status=[OK]
```

I think that some related questions are:
What's the intended use of `servlet-context.xml`, `root-context.xml` and `web.xml`?
Why DispatcherServlet creates another application context?
Context initialization failed or loading properties
How exactly are the root context and the dispatcher servlet context into a Spring MVC web application?

Try to run the example on Eclipse and get the same:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHibernate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

Still not know how to fix and how to detect what is wrong with application.
Thanks for help.

Comment: I think people who can help is: @Neil McGuigan

Comment: And other who can help @Ryan Stewart

Comment: And @Tomasz Nurkiewicz

Comment: And another @M. Deinum

Answer (score 0):

You have one `Controller` on your project, and it handles a certain set of urls.
It is mentioned on the log level `INFO` on your project.

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/persons],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.listPersons(org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/person/add],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.addPerson(com.journaldev.spring.model.Person)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/remove/{id}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.removePerson(int)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/edit/{id}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.editPerson(int,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
```

It is :

```
/persons 
/person/add
/remove/{id}
/edit/{id}
```

The warning you have is because you called an `Url` with this form :

```
http://localhost:xxxx/SpringMVCHibernate/
```

which is not mapped on your servlet.

Comment: When I run project got 404 for http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCHibernate/ Is it what you said?

Comment: @MToma  localhost:8080/SpringMVCHibernate/

Comment: I do not understand what is wrong. How to translate this     WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHibernate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
in plain english?

Comment: I tried to change the in controller "/persons" with "/SpringMVCHibernate/persons" but this doesn't help. I suppose there is something other that have to be changed. I will add more info.

Comment: @MToma,I don't understand your question , what do you think is wrong with your mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

I Tray again the example in Netbeans and make it work. I was wrong by expecting to see a page on url: http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCHibernate If I change the url to: http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCHibernate/persons I get an error:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
…
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class ‘com.mysql.jdbc.Driver’
```

I add the mysql-connector and I see tha right page;
Thanks for any comment
M. Toma